# $this->load function in Core file of codeigniter

Tags: function, codeigniter

I have this in all my Controllers for Menu, but I want to give it once in the core folder of CI Any Suggestions?

```
> $data['cms_menus']=$this->database_model->GetRecords('cms_menus',
> false, array('FKMenuID'=>null));
>         foreach ($data['cms_menus'] as $key => $datas){
>             $data['cms_menus'][$key]['childs']=$this->database_model->GetRecords('cms_menus',
> false, array('FKMenuID'=> $datas['PKMenuID']));
```

Comment: you need to create a core file, then extends from your core and call the method that meke all you need

Answer (score 0):

One way is to extend CI_Controller

```
class MY_Contoller extends CI_Controller
{
  public $data;
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent :: __construct();
    $this->load->model('database_model');
    $data['cms_menus']=$this->database_model->GetRecords('cms_menus', false, array('FKMenuID'=>null));
    foreach ($data['cms_menus'] as $key => $datas)
    {
       $this->data['cms_menus'][$key]['childs']=$this->database_model->GetRecords('cms_menus', false, array('FKMenuID'=> $datas['PKMenuID']));
    }
}
```

Use `MY_Controller` to define the rest of your controllers.

```
class Other_contoller extends MY_Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
      parent :: __construct();
      //other construct code here
   }

   public function index()
   {
      //use the menu in a view
      $this->load->view('some_view', $this->data);
      //The view can use $cms_menus as it is in $this->data
   }
}
```